# Get Count of hard disc accesses in Java

Tags: java, hard-drive, measurement, sigar

I want to measure, how much accesses to the hard disc (so how much Bytes readed / written) a program made. I googled the problem, and found out, that Sigar should be able to record things like that, but after continuing the search, I didn't find anything to get the count of read/writes. Before the program starts, I do

```
sigar = new Sigar();
sigar.enableLogging(true);
```

And afterwars, I do

```
sigar.enableLogging(false);
for ( FileSystem fs : sigar.getFileSystemList() )
{
  if ( fs.getType() == FileSystem.TYPE_LOCAL_DISK )
  {
        System.out.println("Dev: " + fs.getDevName() + ": " + sigar.getDiskUsage(fsName).getReads() +" "+ sigar.getDiskUsage(fsName).getWrites());
  }
}
```

but this doesn't return any sensefull (I've tried it with an java-Program, that just writes Numbers, and it says that there was hard disc usage.

`sigar.getDiscUsage` also seems to only display how big parts of the file system are used, not how much access there has been. Has anybody an hint how to measure this, with sigar or with another library?

Thanks in advance
DaGeRe

Comment: "how much accesses to the hard disc (so how much Bytes readed / written)" They aren't the same thing. You can measure bytes in and out, but you have absolutely no way of knowing how many disc accesses that took.

Answer (score 2):

There's a plugin called Tracer-IO Probes for jvisualvm that allows to count the following:

- File I/O count: Invocations count of read/write operations
- File I/O bytes: Number of bytes read or written to files
- File I/O size: Average number of bytes per one read/write operation

It will show first 1 write count with 22 bytes and then 2 read counts for 22 bytes ...

[jvisualvm IO probes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xoul0.png)

... for this program which writes and reads 22 bytes

```
System.in.read();
byte[] bytes = "Writing this to a file".getBytes();
Path path = Files.createTempFile("io-probes-test", ".txt");
path.toFile().createNewFile();
Thread.sleep(2000L);
Files.write(path, bytes);
Thread.sleep(10000L);
Files.readAllBytes(path);
Thread.sleep(2000L);
path.toFile().delete();
Thread.sleep(5000L);
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage the [OSHI](https://github.com/oshi/oshi) project.  There is an [OSProcess class](http://oshi.github.io/oshi/apidocs/oshi/software/os/OSProcess.html) with methods `getBytesRead()` and `getBytesWritten()` which will return the disc access by that program.

It does not return the exact number of reads/writes at the Process level, but it does at the Device level: the [HWDiskStore class](http://oshi.github.io/oshi/apidocs/oshi/hardware/HWDiskStore.html) has methods `getReads()` and `getReadBytes()` as well as the same for writes, so if you measure both the program and the disk you can probably develop a ratio and have a good estimate for the program itself.

Code to fetch that data... start out with a SystemInfo object:

```
SystemInfo si = new SystemInfo();
```

To get a list of hard disks with both counts and bytes:

```
HardwareAbstractionLayer hal = si.getHardware();
List<HWDiskStore> disks = hal.getDiskStores();
```

To get a list of processes with bytes:

```
OperatingSystem os = si.getOperatingSystem(); 
List<OSProcess> procs = os.getProcesses();
```

or if you know the process ID you are measuring:

```
OSProcess proc = os.getProcess(pid);
```